# jQuery onclick toggle function

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I have the following Foundation toggle element:

```
<div class="switch radius">
  <input id="x" name="switch-x" type="radio" onclick="$(this).revealProfile('no');"checked>
  <label for="x">No</label>

  <input id="x1" name="switch-x" type="radio" onclick="$(this).revealProfile('yes');">
  <label for="x1">Yes</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

When clicked I would like to change the input boolean value of my hidden field from true to false:

```
<input id="real_property_sale_reveal_owner_profile" name="real_property_sale[reveal_owner_profile]" type="hidden" value="false">
```

I've written the following functions to achieve this:

```
$.fn.revealProfile = function(no) {
    $('input#real_property_sale_reveal_owner_profile').val('false');
};
$.fn.revealProfile = function(yes) {
    $('input#real_property_sale_reveal_owner_profile').val('true');
};
```

However, only the last function runs when the toggle is clicked: `$.fn.revealProfile = function(yes)` instead of alternating between the two. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$.fn.revealProfile = function(no) {
    $('input#real_property_sale_reveal_owner_profile').val('false');
};
$.fn.revealProfile = function(yes) {
    $('input#real_property_sale_reveal_owner_profile').val('true');
};
```

to

```
$.fn.revealProfile = function(boolYesNo) {
    var valueToSet = false;
    if(boolYesNo == 'yes'){
        valueToSet = true;
    }
    $('input#real_property_sale_reveal_owner_profile').val(valueToSet);
};
```

The reason the last function was only running is because you defined them both on the same property `revealProfile` for the `prototype` so it was running the most recent function you set. Better to approach like above by passing a parameter instead.

Comment: Ahhh I see thank you. Does this require a change to the HTML onclick event attribute?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor, I don't think it does. Are you still experiencing problems with it?

Comment: I was just double checking. Just tested it and it works perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you've did is define 2 function with the same name, so the last one is used. You can try this.

```
$.fn.revealProfile = function(inputVal) {
    var booleanResult = false;
    if (inputVal === 'yes') {
        booleanResult = true;
    }
    $('input#real_property_sale_reveal_owner_profile').val(booleanResult);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing just a space:

```
<input id="x" name="switch-x" type="radio" onclick="$(this).revealProfile('no');"checked>
```

should be

```
<input id="x" name="switch-x" type="radio" onclick="$(this).revealProfile('no');" checked>
```